# Selenium Firefox Profile not working

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am trying to load my selenium firefox profile and I keep getting the error:

`WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`

The code was working fine 15 minutes ago.. I am not sure what happened.

I have firefox 43.0.4 and selenium 2.49

This is my code that throws an error:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

I am using Windows 7 Professional, Python 2.7.10 | Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)

Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moyp\dev\anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-15-37f7d14be053>", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
  File "C:\Users\Moyp\dev\anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 77, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(self,
  File "C:\Users\Moyp\dev\anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "C:\Users\Moyp\dev\anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "C:\Users\Moyp\dev\anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 103, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Comment: Tested using MacOS, Selenium 2.49 and Firefox 43.0.4 on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 - no errors. Could you share more details about your setup, the code you execute and a complete traceback?

Comment: I just added more details, the code I executed is the 2 lines I posted

Comment: just updated the traceback again, I had the wrong one before

Comment: Just a quick check: could you `import selenium` and print out the `selenium.__version__` in your IPython terminal? Thanks.

Comment: says its '2.46.1', I just restarted pycharm again and it says '2.49' and the code works now. thanks!

Comment: Okay, posted as an answer to resolve the topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different selenium versions have *compatibility issues* with certain Firefox versions. Selenium 2.49 and Firefox 43 work together well.

Make sure you are really using `selenium 2.49`:

```
import selenium
print(selenium.__version__)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue, the issue was after starting virtual display for headless I wasn't stopping it. So all of them were running in background. Run `top` command and check if there is not browser `firefox` running after tests are finished.

Answer (score 2):

There are some know issues with profiles. As per the Selenium release notes you shouldn't be using `profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profilepath)` anymore...